# How to write a VBA script to grab data from website?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I am new to this programming field, currently learning excel VBA scripting. I am having issue with my code, I am trying to pull certain data from [this website](https://www.mcmaster.com/). My main idea is if I enter the product number and quantity details, the particular product details should be stored in my Excel sheet.

Such as if I choose a screw and enter the product number or name of the screw in search bar, it should automatically download technical data of that screw.

So far I have gathered some information and written this code but it's not working.

```
Sub test()


Dim eRow As Long
Dim elemCollection As Object
Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long
Set MyObject = Sheets(1)


Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Thread Size"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Length"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Threading"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Profile"
sht.Range("E" & RowCount) = "Head Diameter"
sht.Range("F" & RowCount) = "Head Height"
sht.Range("G" & RowCount) = "Countersink Angle"
sht.Range("H" & RowCount) = "Drive Style"
sht.Range("I" & RowCount) = "Drive Size"
sht.Range("J" & RowCount) = "Material"
sht.Range("K" & RowCount) = "Thread Type"
sht.Range("L" & RowCount) = "Thread Spacing"
sht.Range("M" & RowCount) = "Thread Fit"
sht.Range("N" & RowCount) = "Head Type"
sht.Range("O" & RowCount) = "System of Measurement"
sht.Range("P" & RowCount) = "Specifications Met"
sht.Range("Q" & RowCount) = "UnitCost"
sht.Range("R" & RowCount) = "QTY"


Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

mypart = InputBox("Please enter the product number")
myQTY = InputBox("No. of Quantity Ordered")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "https://www.mcmaster.com/#screws/=1bj14dv"

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set searchbar = .documents.getElementsByName("srchEntryWebpart_Inpbox")
searchbar.Item(0).Value = mypart

Set qtyinput = .documents.getElementsByName("input-simple--qty")
qtyinput.Item(0).Value = QTY

Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Spec-table--pd").Value
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("searchbar-button").submit

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.className
Case "srchEntryWebpart_Inpbox"
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("E" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("F" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("G" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("H" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("I" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("J" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("K" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("L" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("M" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("N" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("O" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("P" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("Q" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
Case "divider--spec-tbl value-cell--table"
sht.Range("R" & RowCount) = ele.innerText

End Select
Next ele


'For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
    'For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Cells.Length - 1)
        'For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
        'eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
        'Next c
    'Next r
'Next t


End With
Range("A1:R1000").Columns.AutoFit


Set IE = Nothing

'
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\VamsiK\Documents\Mcmaster inventory 1.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the error messages that appear, and indicate where in the code the error occurs? This will help other users diagnose what exactly is going wrong. Also, if you're new to programming in general and not just VBA, you'll save yourself a lot of headache by doing web-scraping with a language like Python or R rather than VBA.

Comment: What's with the 5x `ActiveWorkbook.Save` lines at the end?

Comment: Hi, I am getting Run time error '438'
object doesn't support this property or method.
I didn't know it will be easier in python, otherwise i would have started from there.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and clean up all your variable declarations. There are many examples where it looks like you think you're using one variable but you've actually just created a different one.

Comment: @designerkvnr That error is at `Set searchbar = .doc....`, you didn't declare this variable and therefore vba don't know that it should have the properties of an object. You have done this multiple places. When you are new to VBA and webscrapping, i would test one by one function before continuing. (eg. start with opening the page and add a value to the searchbar, when that works you implement the click event so the search starts and so on) and when you get stuck with one function you can seek help, so you don't have one huge script with alot of erros. (i can see 7 so far, without testing)

Comment: If you know part number, e. g. `91251A051` then you may just make XHR by the URL [`https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1517941469/WebParts/Content/ItmPrsnttnWebPart.aspx?partnbrtxt=91251A051`](https://www.mcmaster.com/mv1517941469/WebParts/Content/ItmPrsnttnWebPart.aspx?partnbrtxt=91251A051), the response contains quite full data, and you may extract details you need. So you do not need IE at all.

Comment: When you search for eg. 91251A051 would you only want that one, or would you want all the screws with in the same group? (Lg. 0 - 80)